# More flexible way to select attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have a list of 565 parcel numbers in a dBase table, I also have a shapefile containing all addresses/parcel numbers in a given area. I would like to create a new layer from the shapefile based on the corresponding parcel values in the dBase table. PLease note that the shapefile may have multiple instances of the same parcel number, where the dBase table does not. This, in a sense, is like a 1 to M relationship, except I want to create a layer with all the related values for all the parcel numbers.

The only way I can think of doing this is to define a relate based on parcel number, select all features in the current table (dBase) and view related table for all values, then export the related table. However with the dBase table containing 565 values and the shapefile containing over a million values, this is a slow inefficient process. Anyone know a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are wanting to accomplish, you want to join the table you have to the feature class (which you can do), then create a new feature class for each parcel number. This can be accomplished by creating a join then iterating through the joined feature class using the group by fields option, then creating a new feature class for each group, in your case parcel number. If this is what you intend to do then the solution is not very difficult.
[image]

You will need to select the field to group by in the iterate feature selection iterator. In this example I am using the parse path tool to take the value of the group and pass it as the name for the feature class. In your case, the parcel number cannot be used by itself, because a feature class name cannot start with a number. The solution to this is to put a prefix in the output name under the feature class to feature class tool. In this case I used FC_ then variable substitution to take the value from the parse path. (See Below) Also make sure you select Name in the drop down menu in the parse path tool.

[image]

I put together a small dataset to test this model and it works fine. Hopefully this will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

These types of workflows are exactly what Model Builder was made for. See the ArcMap help docs to get some help getting started.

Comment: I'm familiar with ModelBuilder... what kind of algorithm are you thinking?

Comment: Iterate through your dBase by whatever field is unique and shared between the features and use it to select from your shapefile. Turn that selection into a new layer named Parcel Number or whatever. Repeat as needed.